# cURL not sending POST data

Tags: php, curl

Maybe I just need a pair of fresh eyes....

I need to POST to a page behind .htaccess Basic Authentication. I successfully log in and get past the .htBA, then POST to the target page. I know that the script is getting to that page as I'm logging the access. However $_POST is empty -- evident from both checking the var as well as the target script not working the way it should. (I control all pages).

I've tried many combos of the various curl opts below to no avail. I'm not getting any errors from the second hit.

Thanks.

```
$post_array = array(
  'username'=>$u,
  'password'=>$p
);


// Login here
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/admin/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('temp/cookies.txt') );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('temp/cookies.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password"),
));
$logInFirst = curl_exec ($ch);


/* Don't close handle as need the auth for next page
 * load up a new page */
$post_array_2 = array(
    'localfile'=>'my_data.csv',
    'theater_mode'=>'normal'
    );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('temp/cookies.txt') );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('temp/cookies.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/admin/post_here.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/admin/post_here.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array_2));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;',
  "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password"),
));
$runAi = curl_exec($ch);
$run_error = curl_error($ch); echo '<hr>'.$run_error.'<hr>';
curl_close($ch);
```

Here's the code on the target page (post_here.php), which results in a zero count. So I know that the target script is being hit, and based on the output, there are no POSTs.

```
$pa = '   There are this many keys in POST: '.count($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $pa .= '   '.$key.':'.$value.'    ----  ';
}
```

Comment: did you check post data or form data in inspect element that send to that page?

Comment: `base64_encode("$username:$password")` and `'username'=>$u,'password'=>$p` - should these be the same? ie: use `$u` rather than `$username` etc

Comment: @RamRaider... this cURL is in a function and `$username = $u` where $u is what is declared in the function params, so they are actually one in the same. (did this for debugging along the way). Thanks.

Comment: **Edit**: The form on the remote page is not actually uploading a file, but rather it's just telling the script the name of the file (`$_POST['localfile']`) that I want to process. The dir that the file resides in is programmatically determined in the processing of the form/post page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on the second request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array_2));
// ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;',
  // ...
```

You send the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` but the data is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (by [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)).

The data you want to post on the second request contains `'localfile'=>'my_data.csv'`. If you want to upload a file on the second request then the content type is correct (but you don't need to set it manually).  Don't use `http_build_query()` but pass an array to  `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, as is [explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-notes).

Also, for file uploads you have to put a `@` in front of the file name and make sure `curl` is able to find the file. The best way to do this is to use the complete file path:

```
$post_array_2 = array(
    'localfile'    => '@'.__DIR__'/my_data.csv',
    'theater_mode' => 'normal'
);
```

The code above assumes `my_data.csv` is located in the same directory as the PHP script (which is not recommended). You should use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to navigate from the script's directory to the directory where the CSV file is stored, to compose the correct path.

As the documentation also states, since PHP 5.5 the `@` prefix is deprecated and you should use the [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class for file uploads:

```
$post_array_2 = array(
    'localfile'    => new CURLFile(__DIR__'/my_data.csv'),
    'theater_mode' => 'normal'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array_2);
```

---

As a side note, when you call `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);` it means `curl` is allowed to negotiate the authentication method with the server. But you also send the header `"Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password")` and this removes any negotiation because it forces `Authorization: Basic`.

Also, in order to negociate, `curl` needs to know the (user, password) combination. You should always use `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password")` to tell it the user and password. Manual crafting the `Authorization` header is not recommended.

If you are sure `Authorization: Basic` is the method you need then you can
use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC)`.

Comment: Ok, this answer is the closest. I believe the main issue was sending the `POSTFIELDS` in the second request. 1). I did take out the `http_build_query()` and instead just used the array directly. 2). In the `HTTPHEADER` curl_setopt, I left as is `'Content-Type: mulitpart/form-data'` and removed the `'Authorization'` element of the array. **Result** this retained the successful hits of the pages, as will as the correct `$_POST` to be accessible in the target script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not see anything inside post because you are using `'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;',`. Just remove that and you should be fine.

If you want to upload a file (i.e. `my_data.csv`) that case you need to follow this way:

```
## change your file name as following in your param
'localfile'=> '@'.'./my_data.csv',

## after that remove http_build_query() from post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array_2);
```

This will automatically add the header `multipart` with your post.

You may look your uploaded file using `$_FILES` variable.

Finally, You can observe what curl is enabling verbose mode.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Tips: While using cookie, always close curl after each and every `curl_exec()` you do. Otherwise it will not probably write things into cookie file after every requests you make!

Comment: RE:Tips I know about writing to cookies with a normal page, that they need to be written to the browser in output for them to be set. Didn't know about cookies in cURL. So, I tried. I closed the first cURL `curl_close($ch)` then I set `curl_init($ch)` to lead off the second call, and I get a 401 Unauthorized. I even tried to set HTTPAUTH, and USERPWD, to no avail. With how I have it written, I know that cURL is successfully hitting both pages. Thanks though.