# How to submit contact form 7 programmatically

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to submit contact form by custom function 
The code below is getting the instance of form but when submitted. It submit the form but not the fields which I wanted.

```
$item = wpcf7_contact_form( $formId );
$result = $item->submit();
```

Here where I can pass the fields I define in admin panel like **"textarea-123"** & **"email-234"** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get exact answer for what I look but I found the alternate solution.

```
function cf7Submit($formId , $args) {
    $url = 'http://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/'.$formId.'/feedback';
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'body'        => $args
        )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    } else {
        echo 'Response:<pre>';
        print_r( $response );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

I can call this function like this:

```
cf7Submit(128, array(
'textarea-123' => 'test email',
'email-234' => 'asd@asd.com'));
```

Comment: As of 5.6 release (6/22) this no longer works unfortunately. 

You'll receive a 415 error of content type not accepted. To fix this, you can add a header with the content type of "multipart/form-data".

After adding the header, the body $args aren't being passed and the form fails to send.

Any ideas on how to make this work with 5.6?

Answer (score 3):

[@daraptoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572935/daraptoor) has found a good solution, but as [@davevsdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3809939/davevsdave) noticed in the comment, it does not work properly in CF7 5.6.

Error 415 is caused by an added to API check for content type passed into a request header:

```php
// part of create_feedback() from CF7's rest-api.php
if ( ! str_starts_with( $content_type, 'multipart/form-data' ) ) {
```

To figure it out, just add the expected content type into a request header:

```php
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'headers'     => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ),
    'body'        => $args
    )
);
```

**UPD**

Faced with an issue, that `wp_remote_post()` sends data in `body` and not in `POST`, so CF7 API does not get any fields. It is caused because the WP's function uses `http_build_query()` (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35250982/14712811)).

I have used the `cURL` request as a workaround:

```php
// CF7 API URL related to CF7 form we want to pass data to using its ID.
$apiUrl = get_site_uri() . '/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/' . $formId . '/feedback';
// Same user agent as in regular wp_remote_post().
$userAgent = 'WordPress/' . get_bloginfo('version') . '; ' . get_bloginfo('url');
// Note that Content-Type is written in a bit different way.
$header = ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data'];
// Same array with fields to pass, not changed.
$body = ['foo' => 'bar'];

$curlOpts = [
    // Send as POST
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    // Get a response data instead of true
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    // CF7 will reject your request as spam without it.
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
];

$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);          // Create a new cURL resource.
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts); // Set options.
$response = curl_exec($ch);        // Grab response.

if (!$response) {
    // Do something if an error occurs.
} else {
    $response = json_decode($response);
    // Do something with the response data.
}

// Close cURL resource, and free up system resources.
curl_close($ch);
```

Hope it saves someone's time :)

**UPD 2**

I have added the missed definition for the `$apiUrl` in the code above.

In `$apiUrl`, I have used another variable `$formId` that is related to the form you want to update. It should be predefined. You can find its ID in the WP admin panel

In my case, I use an ACF field to allow an admin to choose the needed form.

I configured an ACF field on an option page via PHP, so here is the field configuration:

```php
[
    'key' => 'field_blahblahblah', // Unique field key.
    'label' => __('My CF7'), // Any label related to your case.
    'name' => 'cf7_id', // Unique field name to get data later.
    // To allow to choose the needed form and get its ID.
    'type' => 'post_object',
    'post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form',
    'return_format' => 'id',
],
```

For sure, you could configure it from the WP admin.

Then, use your field name to get a form ID:

```php
$formId = get_field('cf7_id', 'options'); // Replace 'cf7_id' with your field name.
```

If you configured it not for an options page, make sure you have used post/page ID instead of `'options'`.

Comment: Hi. Is this the complete solution ? For some odd reason i can't submit my cf7 form with cURL ...

Comment: What is $apiUrl in your code?

Comment: @ArsenK., looks like you were not just copy-paste =). `$apiUrl` is a link to CF7 API. I have updated my answer by adding its definition. Thank you for the question!

Comment: @IonT, probably, because of `$apiUrl` was undefined. I've missed adding its definition. The code has already been updated and you can try it again.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a piece of JS code, like:

`$("form.wpcf7").submit()`

Comment: I want to submit it via PHP not using jQuery.